# Android studio kotlin open camera when ImageButton clicked dont work

Tags: android, kotlin, imagebutton

I need to open camera app when ImageButton is clicked. Here is my code to do this:

```
var btnAddPhoto = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.addPhotoButton)
        btnAddPhoto.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent("MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE")
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
        }
```

But when I run it my activity is changed to previous one. Can you see what is wrong here?

Comment: Which type of issued?

Comment: val cameraIntent: Intent = Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CHOOSH_IMAGE_REQUEST)

Comment: What is CHOOSH_IMAGE_REQUEST and how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

Your intent declaration is wrong, there should be no quotation around `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. Correct initialization looks like following -

```
val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
```

For this you also need to import the package given below

```
import android.provider.MediaStore
```

Comment: @eto123 post the logcat of error to find out exactly where the problem is. Share screenshot of red lines in your logcat.